Speed up / parallelize multivariate_normal.pdf
I have multiple Nx3 points, and I sequentially generate a new value for each from its corresponding multivariate Gaussian, each with 1x3 mean and 3x3 cov. So, together, I have  arrays: Nx3 array of points, Nx3 array of means and Nx3x3 array of covs.
I only see how to do it with the classic for-loop:
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

# Generate example data
N = 5  # Small number for minimal example, can be increased for real use case
points = np.random.rand(N, 3)
means = np.random.rand(N, 3)
covs = np.array([np.eye(3) for _ in range(N)])  # Identity matrices as example covariances

# Initialize an array to store the PDF values
pdf_values = np.zeros(N)

# Loop over each point, mean, and covariance matrix
for i in range(N):
    pdf_values[i] = multivariate_normal.pdf(points[i], mean=means[i], cov=covs[i])

print("Points:\n", points)
print("Means:\n", means)
print("Covariances:\n", covs)
print("PDF Values:\n", pdf_values)

Is there any way to speed this up? I tried to pass all directly to multivariate_normal.pdf, but also from the docs that does not seem to be supported (unlike a simpler case of generating values for Nx3 points, but with same mean and covariance.
Maybe some implementation not from scipy?
I might be too hopeful, but somehow I hope there is a simpler way to speed this up and avoid iterating with this for-loop in a big array of data directly with Pythonic loop.

pdf functions of Scipy are known to be rather slow. Rewriting it in native language (eg. C/C++) or with tools like Cython or Numba often help to get significantly better performance, especially when the code is optimized for your specific needs (here is an example). It also help to easily parallelize the loop. Besides, note that Nx3x3 is generally not a great memory layout performance-wise. 3x3xN is often better.

@JérômeRichard sure, the backup solution would be to rewrite it with some of tools/languages you mentioned, it is just I am barely the only one with this need, so I figured out that someone might have done it already :)

Here is a solution involving Cholesky decomposition.
method 1:
import numpy as np
x = points - means
p = x.shape[1]
res = np.exp(-0.5*(x*np.linalg.solve(covs, x)).sum(1))
res/(2*np.pi)**(p/2)/np.linalg.det(covs)**0.5
array([0.03356053, 0.03167125, 0.08042358, 0.04351325, 0.1328082 ])


method 2:
y = np.linalg.solve(LU := np.linalg.cholesky(covs), points - means)
np.exp(-0.5* (y**2+np.log(2*np.pi)).sum(1))/np.einsum('kii->ki',LU).prod(1)
array([0.03356053, 0.03167125, 0.08042358, 0.04351325, 0.1328082 ])

method 3:
multivariate_normal.pdf(y, np.zeros(p))/np.einsum('kii->ki',LU).prod(1)
array([0.03356053, 0.03167125, 0.08042358, 0.04351325, 0.1328082 ])


method 4: Using svd
U,S,V = np.linalg.svd(covs)
res_svd = np.einsum('ki,kij,kj,kjl,kl->k', x, U, 1/S, V, x)
np.exp(-0.5 * (res_svd + np.log(2 * np.pi * S).sum(1)))
array([0.03356053, 0.03167125, 0.08042358, 0.04351325, 0.1328082 ])

Generate Data:
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal, wishart

# Generate example data
N = 5  # Small number for minimal example, can be increased for real use case
p = 3 # dimension
np.random.seed(10)
points = np.random.rand(N, p)
means = np.random.rand(N, p)
covs = wishart.rvs(p, np.eye(p),N, 2) # Identity matrices as example covariances

# Initialize an array to store the PDF values
pdf_values = np.zeros(N)

# Loop over each point, mean, and covariance matrix
for i in range(N):
    pdf_values[i] = multivariate_normal.pdf(points[i], mean=means[i], cov=covs[i])
pdf_values
array([0.03356053, 0.03167125, 0.08042358, 0.04351325, 0.1328082 ])



Well done! Note that using optimize=True can slightly speed some of the np.einsum up. Method 2 seems the fastest method on my machine for N=500 (with the OP inputs).

@JérômeRichard you could even optimize with np.einsum_path  first. Also I do expect method 2 to be the fastest. The 3rd solution does cholesterol twice

That is amazing and exactly what I was looking for. I took the version number 2. Note that for some reasons numpy 2.0 has issues with it, like with many other things - I decided to stick to numpy 1.X and it worked.

@Valeria you could use scipy.linalg. though not sure it handles 3D. Also to squeeze more speed use numba with scipy.linalg.lapack

@Onyambu actually, that and some other optimizations I made to code, helped so much that now like 90-95% runtime is occupied just by reading the data input... :D So I will focus on that for now, but thanks for hints for future steps.
